# Need any helps wi-th: Buff rangs etc

Tags: azerothcore

My level of English is bad. So I will try to explain by giving examples.

I have `5 items` that are overlaid on the player buff
Let's conditionally call them: 
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
These items have a spell:
`11, 12, 13, 14, 15,`
Binding spells and items:
`1 - 11`,
`2 - 12`,
`3 - 13`,
`4 - 14`,
`5 - 15`,

Question. How to make the player activate, for example, item `2`. But after activation he couldn't use item `1`?

Example:
`43463 Scroll of Agility VII
43464 Scroll of Agility VIII`

That's not in the example. But there is one more thing.  You need to make sure that you cannot use subject `3` after using subject `2`. As long as the spell (`12`) is not over, item `3` (`4.5`) cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to make this in LUA

```
local ItemEntry ={
  --ItemEntry, Spell, PreviousSpell
  {1, 11, 0},
  {2, 12, 11},
  {3, 13, 12},
  {4, 14, 13},
  {5, 15, 14};
}

local function OnUseItem(event, player, itemEntry)
  for i=1, #ItemEntry do
    if itemEntry == ItemEntry[i][1]then
      local pAura = player:HasAura(ItemEntry[i][3])
      if pAura == true then
        local pAura = player:GetAura(ItemEntry[i][3])
        if pAura <= ItemEntry[i][3]then
          player:RemoveAura(ItemEntry[i][3])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
RegisterPlayerEvent(31, OnUseItem)
```

Normally it should work if it returns an error do not hesitate to send it to me on discord

PS: If you are French send a mp in French .. x)

iThorgrim#1138

Comment: Hey, friend. When I filled out the application for help, I made a mistake by writing *lua* in the tags. I tried your script for lua and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Its not about lua or items, its about spells: http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/spell_group_stack_rules
and also need to make item script through module or basic script system, not lua i don't see methods who allows that in eluna module

Comment: This is definetly the way to go.
Also, you can set the same category & category cooldown to prevent from using your spell-item when the player already used one. You can edit it in `Spell.DBC` easily.
But if you want a more proper way, you can add a script for your spell in `spell_generic.cpp` and assign it to your spells in the `world`.`spell_script_names` table.